# How many binary numbers of length n do not contain the substring 000?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, binary

How many binary numbers of length $n$ *do not* contain the substring $000$? Denote this number by $Z_n$; find a relationship between $Z_n$, $Z_{n-1}$, and (something else not given) to form an appropriate recurrence relation. (Do not try to find a closed form).

Comment: Welcome to math. SE. Please share your efforts in solving the problem

Comment: Suppose $n\ge3$. A binary number of length $n$ can either end in $100$, $10$, or $1$ (if it never contains $000$); do you see why?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what parts of the question you don't understand?

Comment: Don't think of them as numbers in binary. Just think of them as a sequence of $1$s and $0$s. This has nothing to do with numeric properties. Then consider Akiva Weinberger's comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I used Akiva's hint and the answers on  [How many length n binary numbers have no consecutive zeroes ?Why we get a Fibonacci pattern?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282875/how-many-length-n-binary-numbers-have-no-consecutive-zeroes-why-we-get-a-fibona) (close to this but only two and not three $0$'s in a row) and came out with

____$n-3$____$100$

____$n-2$____$10$

____$n-1$____$1$

$n$ being the number of strings that do not contain $000$

and got $Z_n$ = $Z_{n-1}$ + $Z_{n-2}$ + $Z_{n-3}$ which is correct (confirmed by my teacher) for anyone else struggling with this problem