# Combinatorial problems in finding the number of subsets of $S_n$

Tags: combinatorics

For $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, let $A'=\{a+1|a \in A\}$. Let $S_n=\{1;2;3;...;n\}$. How many subsets $A$ of $S_n$ satisfying $A \cup A' = S_n$?

I'm trying to solve this problem by using bijection or constructing a sequence but still struggling. Please help me with this.

Comment: Have you tried making examples for small $n?$

Comment: Hint: You can find a recurrence for your answer by conditioning on whether or not $n\in A$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261326/how-many-n-digits-binary-numbers-can-be-formed-where-0-is-not-repeated.